# Send json data in Content of httpresponse in .net core API

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to insert multiple users in database using a API. Now, suppose there are three users to be inserted and assume that one user didn't get inserted but other two are suceessfully inserted. So, I have a requirement to show response which shows that user first is successfully inserted , user 2nd have an error. That is why I have useed list of httpResponseMessage and in each httpresponsemessageobject, I will add complete user json indicating that this was the user, who have failed or success status

So, as per my implementation

I am using foreach loop to insert multiple users in db and returning reponse like this but my respose from api do not shows "user" object in content:

```
public async Task<List<HttpResponseMessage>> InserUsers(JArray obj)
{
List<myDTO> users = obj.ToObject<List<myDTO>>();
List<HttpResponseMessage> list = new List<HttpResponseMessage>();
 foreach (var user in users)
{
    var response = Insert(user);
     list.Add(new HttpResponseMessage
                    {

                        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
                        ReasonPhrase = response.ReasonPhrase,
                        StatusCode = response.StatusCode
                    });

}
return returnResposeList;
}

 public HttpResponseMessage Insert(User user)
{
     // do insert and if there is error

       return new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Error,
                    ReasonPhrase = $"Error"
                };

     else
    {
          return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                ReasonPhrase = $"Successfully inserted"
            };
    }
}
```

Thanks & regards

Comment: Why do you have a `List<HttpResponseMessage>`? How is it used? You should spend a bit more time improving your question so that it can give us a clear picture of what the problem is.

Comment: The below line adds the json to my content but the .net core APi fails to send response now. I don't knwo why?

Content = new ObjectContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user).GetType(), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user),new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() ),

Comment: @Svek, I have just edited question. Does it makes sense?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I still don't understand why you have a `List<HttpResponseMessage>`.

Answer (score 1):

As per some of the comments, I don't understand why you need a status code for each insert rather than returning a bool or something like the inserted Id.

I think something like this works with what you have shown already along with return the user objects:

```
 public async Task<ObjectResult> InserUsers(JArray obj)
    {
        List<myDTO> users = obj.ToObject<List<myDTO>>();
        List<InsertUserResponseDto> list = new List<InsertUserResponseDto>();
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            var isSuccess = Insert(user);
            list.Add(new InsertUserResponseDto
            {
                User = user,
                StatusCode = isSuccess ? StatusCodes.Status200OK : StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
            });

        }

        var isSuccessfullInsert = list.Any(x => x.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status207MultiStatus);
        return StatusCode(isSuccessfullInsert ? StatusCodes.Status207MultiStatus : StatusCodes.Status200OK, list);
    }

    public bool Insert(User user)
    {
        try
        {
            // Complete insert
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log Exception
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class InsertUserResponseDto
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    }
```

I have used the response code of 207 if any of the inserts fail otherwise I have used a 200. Each object within the list will contain the original user object along with an associated status code that you wanted including handling for success and failure.

Answer (score 1):

For `HttpResponseMessage`, it used to describe the whole response, you should avoid returning `HttpResponseMessage` with multiple `HttpResponseMessage`.

For another option, you could try create your own `HttpResponseMessage` like

```
public class ApiResponseMessage
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the reason phrase which typically is sent by servers together with
    //     the status code.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The reason phrase sent by the server.
    public string ReasonPhrase { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the status code of the HTTP response.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The status code of the HTTP response.
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the content of a HTTP response message.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The content of the HTTP response message.
    public object Content { get; set; }

}
```

And then

```
[HttpPost("InserUsers")]
public async Task<List<ApiResponseMessage>> InserUsers()
{
    List<User> users = new List<User> {
        new User{ Name = "Jack" },
        new User{ Name = "Tom"},
        new User{ Name = "Tony"}
    };
    List<ApiResponseMessage> list = new List<ApiResponseMessage>();
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var response = Insert(user);
        list.Add(new ApiResponseMessage
        {

            Content = new { user },
            ReasonPhrase = response.ReasonPhrase,
            StatusCode = response.StatusCode
        });

    }
    return list;
}

public ApiResponseMessage Insert(User user)
{
    // do insert and if there is error
    if (user.Name == "Tom")
    {
        return new ApiResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
            ReasonPhrase = $"Error"
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return new ApiResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            ReasonPhrase = $"Successfully inserted"
        };
    }
}
```